# Image is not showing (one image is showing and another image is not showing )

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

**Servlets program**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Redirect
 */
@WebServlet("/Redirect")
public class Redirect extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("servlet is intialized");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/myhtml.jsp").forward(request, response);     

    }



}
```

**JSP file**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8">
<title>NewFile.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.gmail.com"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/gmailimage.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="http://www.yahoomail.com"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/yahooimage.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
</body>
</htm
```

image folder is --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/558ON.png .My problem is Gmail image is showing but Yahoomail image is not showing.Result -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5AT.png .why like this,whats the wrong .suggest me with your valuable thoughts.

Comment: You should check the name of your image.

Comment: currect name i provide have any doubt see what i provide links  http://i.stack.imgur.com/558ON.png  and  http://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5AT.png

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself? like write **href** tag of yahoo above to that of gmail. Is it working fine?

Comment: if i rename both image with gmailimage it showing perfectly gmail symbol but when place yahooimage ,image is not showing.why?

Comment: here only problem with yahooimage.what that problem?

Comment: i placed another image instead of yahooimage but still same problem

Comment: code looks fine for now. but you should do some changes on your own. Either you are not posting your problem or you are not getting where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried checking image URL? 
Using Chrome's developer tool (F12) you can pick an element and check inside its properties. Look at its URL and try to copy&paste it into address bar.

Probably you won't see it, and then you can try adjusting the URL by hand.

Comment: ya am accessing image through web browser like file:///home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/rocking/Examples/WebContent/images/

Comment: I can't understand. request.getContextPath() doesn't return a local file system path, then you cannot have a path starting with "file:///" as the result of `<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/yahooimage.jpg" width="1..`

What is value of src attribute in the page from your browser?

Comment: @servletsram : also avoid using Scriptlets, they're pure evil.Use EL+JSTL, or OGNL+S2 instead.